# Alternate Excel row color on value change in table

Tags: excel

I want to format Excel data that is in a table based on a changes to a value in a column, and perform this formatting dynamically. First image is default formatting; second image is desired formatting.

I have found ways to do this dynamically with a helper column when the data is not formatted as a table, but would prefer to keep the data formatted as a table.

[image: Default table formatting]

[image: Desired table formatting]

Comment: Use Conditional formatting. Pretty easy in your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image][![enter image description here][2]][2]You Need to use Condition Formatting --> New Rule --> and then select "use a formula to determine which cells to format" to achieve this.

You need to use a control column to determine the value of the reference cell. and use that control column values use as the key to the conditional formatting. In my case I put "=ISEVEN($G10)" in the formula to achieve this, where column G holds the values 1, 2,2,3,...

```
Version Control Column  Formula in Conditional formatting           
    formula = "=IF(F10=F11,G10,G10+1)"  =ISEVEN($G10)           
a   1   FALSE           Odd
b   2   TRUE            Even
b   2   TRUE            Even
c   3   FALSE           Odd
c   3   FALSE           Odd
d   4   TRUE            Even
d   4   TRUE            Even
e   5   FALSE           Odd
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

Comment: Can you include row/column headers in the screenshot? From what's posted it looks like first value (1) in "Control Column" is cell G10, but that means the (1) is either hard-coded or a circular reference.

Comment: Yes, in my case I put the very first value as 1 and it is hard coded. rest of the values are calculated based on the formula. I am uploading the screenshot with row and column headers

Comment: 1. Because my data included color formatting from the "Format as table" options, I had to create one rule for "=ISEVEN..." and a second rule for "=ISODD..."

2. Note that the "Control Column" has to be populated when new data is entered.

Comment: if you have large volume of data, then the value in the control column will be very large eventually. To avoid this, you may want to use this formula in cell G11 , which will return only 1 or 2 in the control column. =IF(AND(G11=1,F11=F12),1,IF(AND(F11=F12,G11=2),2,IF(AND(G11=1,F11<>F12),2,IF(AND(F11<>F12,G11=2),1))))

Comment: Also for the control column you can add a check like isblank(). and copy the formula to a large number of rows that you will use in the future with new data. This will help you to eliminate the need of populating control column every time you enter data in the main table.  =if(isblank(g12),"",IF(AND(G11=1,F11=F12),1,IF(AND(F11=F12,G11=2),2,IF(AND(G11=‌​1,F11<>F12),2,IF(AND‌​(F11<>F12,G11=2),1))‌​))

Comment: I just saw one error in my comment. The formulas are copied from G12, not G11 as I mentioned in last two comments. But the methodologies and formulas are fine